# Table with multiple buttons - need to get the value of the button that I click on in php.

Tags: php, forms

The table below contains buttons with values. When a button is clicked I want to proceed "predictSeason.php". Say I want to print/echo the team I selected there (i.e the value of clicked button) - how should I do this?

```
<table class ="teamTable">
    <form action="predictSeason.php" method="post">
      <?php
      $number_per_row = 5;
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($soccerseason->getTeams() as $team) {
          if (($i % $number_per_row) == 0) {
              echo '<tr>';
          }
          ?>
        <td class="crestTd"style="background-image:url(<?php echo $team->crestUrl ?>);">
          <button id="button<?php echo $i ?>" name="button<?php echo $i ?>" class="tableButton" value="<?php echo $team->name ?>"></button>
        </td>
        <?php
        if (($i % $number_per_row) == $number_per_row - 1) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }
          $i = $i + 1;
      }
      ?>
    </form>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write

```
    <table class ="teamTable">
    <form action="predictSeason.php" method="post">
      <?php
      $number_per_row = 5;
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($soccerseason->getTeams() as $team) {
          if (($i % $number_per_row) == 0) {
              echo '<tr>';
          }
          ?>
        <td class="crestTd"style="background-image:url(<?php echo $team->crestUrl ?>);">
          <button id="button<?php echo $i ?>" name="button<?php echo $i ?>" class="tableButton" value="<?php echo $team->name ?>" type="submit" ></button>
        </td>
        <?php
        if (($i % $number_per_row) == $number_per_row - 1) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }
          $i = $i + 1;
      }
      ?>
    </form>
  </table>
```

Comment: What should I write in predictSeason.php to print the value from the submit button?

Comment: You can fetch the result from your submit button and then simply echo the result in your `predictSeason.php` @nisseman